# MS Access: Copy/paste data validation rules to multiple fields?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, relational

first time asker here, let me know how I can improve!
I've searched Google and Stack Overflow already, but perhaps I'm not asking the right question since I'm quite new to Access.

I'm building a data-entry form for a healthcare questionnaire.  I have several fields that should be answered **Y/N/Unk**.  I would like to apply **data validation** to all these fields.  Since there are about four-dozen fields, I'd prefer not to do this by hand each time.

Ex:

```
Y    N    Unk     Symptom
[]   []   []      Nausea
[]   []   []      Vomiting
etc.
```

Alternately, is there a way to simply create a table with my desired answers (Y/N/Unk) and apply combo boxes that reference the "Y/N" Table, and apply this reference in bulk to many fields on the data-entry form?

I'm new to Access, unfortunately don't know any VBA.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tomalak rightly says, using relationships is the correct way to do this.  As you are new to Access, though, you might find the following useful.

First create yourself a table, call it whatever you want, but for my example I am calling it YNU.  This table needs only two fields, an ID, which should be an integer and needs to be the primary key (you can also use Auto-Number, if you want) and a Description field, which should be Short Text.  Save the new table and then open it.  Now add values, Unknown, Yes and No in the Description field.  If you have used Auto-Number you don't need values in the ID field (Access provides them automatically), otherwise add them yourself (eg 0, 1, 2 respectively).

Now open your Patients table (or whatever you call it) in design view and make sure that the data type for Nausea, Vomiting and whatever else you want is the same as the ID data type in YNU (save if you have made changes).  If you used Auto-Number, then the data type must be Long Integer. Next, select Relationships on the Design Tab.  Use Show Table so that you have YNU and Patients open.  Now drag the ID field from the YNU table onto the Nausea field in the Patients table.  A popup dialog appears, allowing you to define how the Relationship works.  You will notice that Access automatically knows that the relationship will be "One-to-Many"; this is because you will have many unknown/yes/no in the Patients table for Nausea, but there is only one each of unknown yes and no in the YNU table.  Now check the box Enforce Referential Integrity and click the Button Create.  Next use Show Table again to display a second YNU table, and drag the ID to Vomiting.  Repeat for as many fields as you need.  Each relationship will need a new box for the YNU table.  When you are finished save and close the Relationships layout.

Now when designing the form to use for your Patients table, you can select Combo Box from the Toolbox.  After you have drawn the Combo Box on your form, another popup appears.  Accept the default suggestion (I want the combo box to get the values from another table or query) and click Next.  Select YNU from the List of Tables, and click Next.  Now use the double arrow button, to move the two fields ID and Description to the right hand (empty) column. Click Next and in the first Sort select the ID field and Click Next.  You will now see that Access automatically suggests hiding the Key field (ID) and gives a suggested width for the combo box, based on the values in the table. Again accept the default and click Next.  Now change the default to "Store that value in this field:" and select the Nausea field from the Patients table.  One more Next and you can give the combo box an appropriate label.  Finish.  Repeat for as many combo boxes as you need.

Having done this, Access now handles all the data validation for you.  You will only be able to select one of the three possible values.

EDIT

After your comment, I realised that doing it this way (through the wizards), would be slow, if you have so many relationships to create.  In this case, you can do it via DDL (Data Definition Language).  Create a new query (using Query Design); close the Show Table popup without selecting anything; switch to SQL View (large button top left).  Now you will be able to enter a statement like the following and run it (Run on design Tab):

```
ALTER TABLE Patients ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BrokenBones_YNU FOREIGN KEY (BrokenBones) REFERENCES YNU(Id)
```

You will need only to change two things for each field that you need a relationship; firstly the name of the relationship (above FK_BrokenBones_YNU), and secondly the name of the field (above BrokenBones).

Technically the relationship is a restriction, hence in DDL it is a `CONSTRAINT` and is based on the primary key in a different table, hence the term `FOREIGN KEY`.

As far as the name you choose for the relationship, you are free to use whatever you like, as long as it is not the same as one you have used before!  Many people follow a practice of starting with FK to symbolise that it is a `FOREIGN KEY` and then include the name of the field and table whose primary key is used.  Technically you can create a `FOREIGN KEY` based on a field that is not the primary key for its table, but in this case there must be a unique index on it.  In our case we do not need to concern ourselves with such subtleties.

Comment: I must be a new guy, I didn't expect answers so quickly!  Thank you, I ran through these instructions, and this seems to be working pretty well.  It seems that I'm going to have more tables than I expected.  It's unfortunate I need to link all 40 signs/symptoms to the YNU table one by one.  Count the time requirement as job security I guess?

Comment: Please see my edit.  Note however that you only need one extra table (YNU) to handle all of the references.  It only appears in the relationship wizard that you have multiple tables, but they are all in fact the same table, just different relationships.

Comment: @captaincaed If you have 40 symptoms and all can be "yes"/"no"/"unknown", you should not have a table 40 columns with 40 foreign keys, that's bad DB design. That's what I meant to show with my table `question` below. If there are 40 questions to ask ("symptoms to check") then it should be 40 rows in the `question` table. This way you can add more questions without modifying the database structure. Don't think of databases as Excel sheets on steroids, don't try to extend things by adding more columns, that's not how this is supposed to work.

Comment: @Tomalak You are of course quite right.  The only problem with this approach though is that the Access form to update the information would need to be dynamically generated.  This may be one step too far for the OP.  I was assuming that the OP will be using the wizards to generate his form.

Comment: Sorry I've been absent a few days, other life demands.  I do see the logic behind the design @Tomalak advocated.  However at this early stage I don't know what dynamic form generation is, or how to cope with it.  In addition, not every question on the form can be answered with Y/N/U, so I'm not sure how to manage the "choice" table with this relationship setup.  I may need to do bad design for now just to get this done, either that or hard code some data validation rules line by line...

Comment: I'm relying on wizards for the forms.  It's a summer internship, about 80-100 patients enrolled.  I might be able to skate with bad design for now while I learn to do things properly.  Think it's workable the way @JonathanWillcock suggested?

Comment: It will definitely work, and the wizards will help you create the form. It is just a little inelegant. You can build the form dynamically, but it involves quite a bit of coding. If you wanted to go this way, you woul have a form with the basic details and then add the YNU questions in a loop within the form open event to add as many dropdowns as you need. It can be done, but it is not easy for someone not experienced with VBA.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for framing what the procedure would have been.  I can build loops in R, but I have no knowledge of VBA syntax so I think that's a deep rabbit hole for essentially 2 more weeks on the job.

Answer (score 3):

> Alternately, is there a way to simply create a table with my desired answers (Y/N/Unk) and apply combo boxes that reference the "Y/N" Table, and apply this reference in bulk to many fields on the data-entry form?

Yes, and that's the way this should be done in a relational database. Create tables and link them with foreign keys. Let's assume a very simple case where there only is a single questionnaire that will never change and will be done for multiple patients:

```
question            patient           result              choice
-------------       -----------       ------------        -----------
question_id   <--+  patient_id  <---- patient_id       +- choice_id
question_text    |  name           +- question_id      |  choice_text
any              |  dob            |  choice_id     <--+
other            |  change_date    |  created_date
info             |  change_date    |  change_date
                 |                 |
                 +-----------------+
```

When you link foreign keys like this, Access will make sure that only valid choice can be entered.

Comment: Thank you, the detailed instructions plus this visual schema really tied it all together.  Great experience for my first question, thank you both.